# Django admin css not working after collectstatic

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I started my website on "pythonanywhere" and ran bash command to 'collectstatic', but then the admin css looks broken.
Is there a way to bring back the django default admin css?

Comment: Have you set up the static files system on PythonAnywhere so that it knows how to serve your CSS/image files?  [This help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles) has the details.

Comment: ahh yes correct. My static path is pointing to somewhere else. Thanks Giles